# Retrieve authentication token from api via post

Tags: php, api, authentication, post

Im trying to build an app that uses the simplenote api but I am having trouble with the authentication part. I am getting a 400 error(bad request).
Im guessing this issue is not related to the simplenote api, it's rather my understanding of the documentation.

Here is what the api is saying:

> HTTP POST to the following URL:
>   https://simple-note.appspot.com/api/login
>
> The body of the request should contain this, but base64-encoded:
>   email=[email-address]&password=[password]
>
> To be clear, you will concatenate email= with the user’s email address (trimmed), 
>   &password=, and the user’s password; then base64 the resulting string and send it as 
>   the HTTP request body. (Do not encode this request using the standard variable 
>   encoding used for POSTed web forms. We basically ignore the Content+Type header 
>   for this request, but text/plain makes the most sense here.)

And here is my code so far:

```
    $url = 'https://simple-note.appspot.com/api/login';
    $data = array('email' => base64_encode($email), 'password' => base64_encode($password));

    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data),
        ),
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what they mean is:

```
$data = base64_encode(http_build_query(array(
    "email" => $email,
    "password" => $password
));
```

So base64 encode the resulting string, not the individual parts.

As for making the request. I can recommend you take a look at `cURL`, it's *much* faster than `file_get_contents`.